# Why doesn't an autoencoder with enough parameters learn perfect answers

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, autoencoder

I've got a basic autoencoder in pytorch using:

```
class Autoencoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Autoencoder, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.Linear(measure_size*4*categories, first_mid_size, dtype=the_dtype),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.02),
            nn.Linear(first_mid_size, second_mid_size, dtype=the_dtype),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.02),
        )
        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(second_mid_size, first_mid_size, dtype=the_dtype),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.02),
            nn.Linear(first_mid_size, measure_size*4*categories, dtype=the_dtype),
            nn.Unflatten(1, (measure_size*4, categories)),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.encoder(x)
        x = self.decoder(x)
        return x
```

My input is one_hot representation of 16*4 values (40 categories).
I'm training using:

```
autoencoder = Autoencoder().to(device)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(autoencoder.parameters(), lr=0.001)
scheduler = optim.lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau(optimizer, verbose=True)
batch_size = 64

...

for ...
    outputs = autoencoder(train_inputs).softmax(dim=2)
    loss = criterion(outputs, train_inputs)
    loss.backward()
```

I expected that if I set the `first_mid_size` and `second_mid_size` to the same size as the input data (`16*6*40 = 2560`), the network will be able to learn the to map 1:1 at some point and get close to 0 loss - but that's not happening. Whether I use layer sizes 2560,2560, or 128,64, I arrive at almost exactly the same loss.

What am I missing here?

(Using MSE instead of CrossEntropy works slightly better, but still not reaching the perfect answers.)

Comment: Maybe ask on datascience.stackexchange.com

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/441750/why-cant-this-autoencoder-reach-zero-loss)